# Hibernate: Query for join with SubQuery

Tags: hibernate

I need to convert below query to hibernate -

```
select * from ep_batch eb
INNER JOIN ep_slide slide ON eb.batch_scanner_id  = slide.slide_batch_id
WHERE eb.batch_scanner_id = 1 AND 
eb.batch_status = 
(
IF((SELECT count(batch_id) as cnt from ep_batch WHERE batch_scanner_id = 1) =1,'Ready','In Progress')
) ;
```

I do have the "Slide" and "Batch" pojo represents ep_slide  and ep_batch  resp. with join annotations as  -

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "batch")
    private Set<Slide> slides;
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "batchId")
    private Batch batch;
```

I am not very sure how to add the subquery with conditions. 
I am trying something like below -

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Slide.class);
        subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.count("batchId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't executed, but you can try the below HQL, replacing the entity properties appropriately.

```
SELECT b FROM Batch b, Slide s 
WHERE b.batch_scanner_id = s.slide_batch_id AND 
b.batch_status = 
(CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(bt.batch_id) FROM Batch bt WHERE bt.batch_scanner_id = 1) = 1) THEN 'Ready' 
ELSE 'In Progress' 
END);
```